# Is there any way to use TFS SOAP/ASMX instead of TF command from a client

Tags: tfs, tfvc, tfs-sdk

Is there any way to use TFS Server SOAP/ASMX instead of **tf command** from the client side, for example, if I want to use

```
http://myServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection/VersionControl/v5.0/repository.asmx
```

--> operation **Get** or operation **CheckIn**;  obviously I need to be previously authenticated

but, is there any example or way to do all the steps with ASMXs instead of using the **tf** command of TFVC?

I am not talking about Azure DevOps REST API, but I am trying with asmx/SOAP webservices:

```
http://myServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection/VersionControl/v5.0/repository.asmx 
http://myServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection/ Services/v3.0/LocationService.asmx
```

Comment: **Accessing these APIs  is unsupported and absolutely not recommended**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Accessing these APIs directly is unsupported, undocumented and absolutely not recommended**

The supported pathway is to use the Azure DevOps Client Object Model (or older TFS client Object Model) or the Team explorer EveryWhere Java API.

- [NuGet for the .NET client object model](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/16.167.0-preview)
- [Repo for the Team Foundation Server/Team Services SDK for Java](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere)

Tf.exe is built on these libraries, as is team explorer. Anything there tools can, you can with this API. Easiest way to see how it does it is to pull tf.exe through a decompiler.

[image]

Comment: Dear @jessehouwing, is possible to UnLock specific files of TFVC with Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi ?

Comment: Sure. Tf.exe is built on these libraries, as is team explorer. Anything there tools can, you can with this API. Easiest way to see how it does it is to pull tf.exe through a decompiler.